# Is there a function which gets to be called when somebody closes executing php script from command line?

Tags: php

I want somehow normally end up my command line php scripts, they get no input from command line and I want to manage some correct shutdown with saving whole progress... Can it be running and waiting for command at the same time? Anything how can I do it without build-in webserver and client-server real time communication using sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be, to be honest I didn't test it, but reading [register_shutdown_function's doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), I found this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#26251).

You need to install [pcntl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) which will allow you to catch the signal you're interested in.

```
function sigint()
{
    //do some shutdown related stuff
}
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sigint');
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sigint');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Super duper answer. Haven't tested it either. But it seems... Going good.